# How to put the content into the panel body?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to make a hanoi tower demo in jsfiddle.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/timwzw/8tQd8/)

#### The Promblem

I use panel component in Bootstrap.css, the problem is I can't put my hanoi tower in to the panel body.

Like this:
[image: before change position]
<sub>(source: [wuzhiwei.net](http://wuzhiwei.net/problems/out-b.png))</sub>

But When I change

```
#peg1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
```

to

```
#peg1 {
    position:static;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
```

I got this:

[image: after change position]
<sub>(source: [wuzhiwei.net](http://wuzhiwei.net/problems/in-b.png))</sub>

### My Question

How can I put the hanoi tower in panel body with the right position of pegs?

Comment: What is the right position of pegs? Is your ` position:static;` not a good solution because the result is not right or because this is not a long-term fix?

Comment: @Anthony The right position is in image1 but it's not in panel body.

Comment: "absolute positioned elements are removed from the flow" -- this is apparently the issue. The fix would be to use another method (like the one suggested) to stretch your divs instead of using the position approach.  This way the wrapper isn't "empty" and keeps its height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to put your tower in the panel :

*This way doesn't use absolute position*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/122444

**CSS**:

```
.peg {
    width:10px;
    height:120px;
    background:black;
    margin : 0px 50px 0px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#base {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:-5px;
    width:270px;
    height:15px;
    background:black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Hanoi Tower</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="hanoi col-xs-12">
                <div class="peg" id="peg1"></div>
                <div class="peg" id="peg2"></div>
                <div class="peg" id="peg3"></div>
                <div class="disc" id="disc1"></div>
                <div class="disc" id="disc2"></div>
                <div class="disc" id="disc3"></div>
                <div class="disc" id="disc4"></div>
                <div class="disc" id="disc5"></div>
                <div id="base"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying a height to `.panel-body`, for eg:

```
.panel-body{
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: The only downside to this is that it visually looks right, but the elements are still not actually "contained" in the div, so the height can't ever be truly dynamic based on the height of the child elements (so resizing or using fluid units, etc, would not work).